# Unable to connect http://localhost/phpmyadmin for xampp v3.2.4, php7.4.9

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP, PHP version7.4.9 in windows 7 ultimate. Installation is successful http://localhost is working fine. But when trying to open phpmyadmin i.e http://localhost/phpmyadmin blank page appearing. I have also tried to change port number say 80 to 8011, 443 to 444 but nothing change. Please advise. Thank you

Comment: You need to check your `xampp apache logs` and let us know the error here.

Comment: [Sun Sep 06 10:21:18.595284 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9152:tid 256] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 06 10:21:18.691290 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9152:tid 256] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 06 10:21:18.747293 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9152:tid 256] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: I installed 7.2.33, then http://localhost/phpmyadmin working fine, but don't know what is the problem for 7.3 & 7.4